# Why do I get an InvalidOperationException (cross-thread operation not valid) when processing ribbon click events?

Tags: c#, vsto, async-await, c#-5.0

I've created a "progress/cancel" mechanism for my application whereby I can show a modal dialog while executing long-running operations, and have the dialog give some indication of progress. The dialog also has a cancel button to allow the user to cancel the operation. (Thanks to the SO community for helping me with this part).

Here's what the code looks like for running a dummy long-running operation:

```
    public static async Task ExecuteDummyLongOperation()
    {
        await ExecuteWithProgressAsync(async (ct, ip) =>
        {
            ip.Report("Hello world!");
            await TaskEx.Delay(3000);
            ip.Report("Goodbye cruel world!");
            await TaskEx.Delay(1000);
        });
    }
```

The parameters to the lamba are a `CancellationToken` and an `IProgress`. I'm not using the `CancellationToken` in this example, but the `IProgress.Report` method is setting the text for a label control on my progress/cancel form.

If I start this long-running operation from the button click handler on a form, it works fine. However, I've now discovered that if I start the operation from the click event handler for a ribbon button in a VSTO PowerPoint add-in, it fails at the *second* call to `ip.Report` (at the point where it tries to set the text of the label control). In this case, I get the dreaded `InvalidOperationException` saying that there's an invalid cross-thread operation.

There are two things that I find puzzling:

- Why does the problem occur when the operation is invoked by clicking a button on the ribbon but not when invoked by clicking a button on a form?
- Why does the problem occur at the second call to `ip.Report` but not at the first? I've not switched threads between those two calls.

You will of course want to see the rest of the code. I've tried to strip everything back to the bare bones:

```
using System;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;


namespace AsyncTestPowerPointAddIn
{
    internal partial class ProgressForm : Form
    {
        public ProgressForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        public string Progress
        {
            set
            {
                this.ProgressLabel.Text = value;
            }
        }

        private void CancelXButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.Cancel;

            this.Close();
        }


        public static async Task ExecuteDummyLongOperation()
        {
            await ExecuteWithProgressAsync(async (ct, ip) =>
            {
                ip.Report("Hello world!");
                await TaskEx.Delay(3000);
                ip.Report("Goodbye cruel world!");
                await TaskEx.Delay(1000);
            });
        }

        private static async Task ExecuteWithProgressAsync(Func<CancellationToken, IProgress<string>, Task> operation)
        {
            var cancellationTokenSource = new CancellationTokenSource();

            var progress = new Progress<string>();

            var operationTask = operation(cancellationTokenSource.Token, progress);


            // Don't show the dialog unless the operation takes more than a second

            const int TimeDelayMilliseconds = 1000;

            var completedTask = TaskEx.WhenAny(TaskEx.Delay(TimeDelayMilliseconds), operationTask).Result;

            if (completedTask == operationTask)
                await operationTask;


            // Show a progress form and have it automatically close when the task completes

            using (var progressForm = new ProgressForm())
            {
                operationTask.ContinueWith(_ => { try { progressForm.Close(); } catch { } }, TaskScheduler.FromCurrentSynchronizationContext());

                progress.ProgressChanged += ((o, s) => progressForm.Progress = s);

                if (progressForm.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.Cancel)
                    cancellationTokenSource.Cancel();
            }

            await operationTask;
        }
    }
}
```

The form itself simply has a label (`ProgressLabel`) and a button (`CancelXButton`).

The button click event handlers for both the ribbon button and the form button simply call the `ExecuteDummyLongOperation` method.

---

**EDIT: More Information**

At @JamesManning's request, I put in some tracing to watch the value of the ManagedThreadId, as follows:

```
            await ExecuteWithProgressAsync(async (ct, ip) =>
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("A:" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString());

                ip.Report("Hello world!");

                System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("B:" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString());

                await TaskEx.Delay(3000);

                System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("C:" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString());

                ip.Report("Goodbye cruel world!");

                System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("D:" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString());

                await TaskEx.Delay(1000);

                System.Diagnostics.Trace.TraceInformation("E:" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId.ToString());
            });
```

This was interesting. When invoked from the form, the thread ID does not change. However, when invoked from the ribbon, I get:

```
powerpnt.exe Information: 0 : A:1
powerpnt.exe Information: 0 : B:1
powerpnt.exe Information: 0 : C:8
powerpnt.exe Information: 0 : D:8
```

So, the thread ID is changing when we 'return' from that first await.

I'm also surprised that we see "D" in the trace at all, since the call immediately prior to that is where the exception occurs!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the expected outcome if the current thread, the one that you called ExecuteDummyLongOperation() on, doesn't have a synchronization provider.  Without one, the continuation after the *await* operator can only run on a threadpool thread.

You can diagnose this by putting a breakpoint on the await expression.  Inspect the value of System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.Current.  If it is *null* then there is no synchronization provider and your code will fail as expected when you update the form from the wrong thread.

It isn't entirely clear to me why you don't have one.  You get a provider by creating a form on the thread, **before** calling the method.  That automatically installs a provider, an instance of the WindowsFormsSynchronizationContext class.  Looks to me like you create your ProgressForm too late.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense (at least as far as my limited understanding of the treading stuff will take me). And you're right, it's `null` in the case where the problem occurs.

Comment: And yes, if I change `ExecuteWithProgressAnsyc` so that the `using` surrounds the entire method, it all just works. Thank you so much!

Comment: ahhh, great catch - I didn't even notice that you were doing awaits before the form creation.  Glad to see you figured it out!

Comment: @HansPassant: an additional question on this, if I may. Do I need to keep the form (or other control) alive / in scope thereafter, in order to keep my sync context alive, or will the sync context live on even when the form/control is closed/disposed?

Comment: Yes.  It doesn't actually have anything to do with the sync context, it is permanently installed.  You just can't invoke to a UI object that no longer exists.  The Handle property is essential to find the right sync context.  There can be more than one, it is a [ThreadStatic] variable.  The underlying winapi function is GetWindowThreadProcessId().